# PHP MVC CRUD Issue

Tags: php

Trying to build my first MVC CRUD application with just PHP (no frameworks).  I've written out my model for the Update but when I click my submit button I'm not getting any updates.

Constants for the __construct are good - they work find in my read model.

Here is my model:

```
<?php
class ModifyModel{

    private $db;

    public function __construct($dsn, $user, $pass){

        try {
        $this->db = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

        }
        catch (\PDOException $e) {
            echo"Couldn't access";
        }
    } //__construct

    public function modUser(){

        $first = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["firstName"]);
        $last = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lastName"]);
        $handle = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["handle"]);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
        $unique = ($_POST["uniqueId"]);

        $statement = $this->db->prepare("
        UPDATE admin
        SET firstName='$first', lastName='$last', handle='$handle', email='$email'
        WHERE uniqueId= '$unique'");
            try {
                $statement->execute();
                echo"success";
                }
        catch (\PDOException $e) {
            echo "Couldn't query the database!";
            var_dump($e);
        }
        return array();
    }
}

?>
```

And here is my controller for it:

```
<?php
    require_once "db.php";
    require_once "UserModel.php";
    require_once "UserView.php";

    $model = new UserModel(MY_DSN, MY_USER, MY_PASS);
    $view = new UserView();
    $view->showHeader('LiveTweet Admin');
    $view->showUpdateUser($model->getModifyUser($_GET["id"]));

    if (isset($_POST ['update'])){
        $model = new modUser();   
    }
    $view->showFooter();
?>
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.  I'm super new to PHP, so I'm sorry if this should be obvious to me.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your class ModifyModel is not being used, you are using UserModel

Comment: Your model class is `ModifyModel`, yet in your controller your trying to create a new instance of `UserModel` ?

Comment: I didn't even catch that - thanks so much...up and running now!

Comment: As a recommendation, you should try to create a bootstrap file so that you don't have to use requires and includes every single time you need one.

This a MVC "Framework" that I built for learning purposes.. it's far from perfect, but the index.php and bootstrap.php files illustrate exactly what I'm telling you (autoload your classes without requires and includes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your controller, you want to instantiate the class `ModifyModel` and then call `modUser` function on that instance.

Try the following:

```
if (isset($_POST ['update'])){
    $modifyModel = new ModifyModel(MY_DSN, MY_USER, MY_PASS);
    $result = $modifyModel->modUser();   
}
```